# Smart split large text into words and signs, like spaces and other characters

Tags: regex, string, scala, replace

I'm working on web-application for text processing. I need split string(text) into words and signs, like spaces and other characters(comma, dot, semicolon, e.g.) Every word and every sign i need to wrap into html tag. Every tag must have an id attribute, that contains word(sign) ordinal number in the text. This processing will work in the Java Servlet and this mean that perfomance is important. Proccessed text may contains 3000 - 5000 words.

Here is a sample input:

```
One two three, four five six seven eight nine.
```

Here is a sample output:

```
<span id="w1" class="word">One </span><span id="w2" class="space">&nbsp;</span><span id="w3" class="word">two</span><span id="w4" class="space">&nbsp;</span><span id="w5" class="word">three</span><span id="w6" class="sign">,</span><span id="w7" class="space">&nbsp;</span><span id="w8" class="word">four</span><span id="w9" class="space">&nbsp;</span><span id="w10" class="word">five</span><span id="w11" class="space">&nbsp;</span><span id="w12" class="word">six</span><span id="w13" class="space">&nbsp;</span><span id="w14" class="word">seven</span><span id="w15" class="space">&nbsp;</span><span id="w16" class="word">eight </span><span id="w17" class="space">&nbsp;</span><span id="w18" class="word">nine</span><span id="w19" class="sign">.</span>
```

Thanks to all for any advice how i can do it.

**Update:** The code below splits string by non alphanumeric symbols

```
text.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")
```

and this code:

```
text.split("\\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\b")
```

splits string by words, but i don't understand how to combine regex for split by words and non alphanumeric symbols?

**Update2:**

It seems like it is answer:

```
val text = "Hello from Scala - regex  world!"
val pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9|а-яА-Я0-9]|\\b[a-zA-Z0-9|а-яА-Я0-9]+\\b".r
pattern.findAllIn(text).matchData foreach {
  m => println("'" + m.group(0) + "'")
}
```

The part of patterns after the "|" sign it is Cyrillic pattern for:

```
a-zA-Z0-9
```

Comment: I suggest you replacing cyrillic words with english ones so that our non-slavonic friends can participate freely as well

Comment: I second serejja's comment (although I would say "Latin-alphabet-based" instead, as only 1 in 3 of the [Slavic language groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_languages) uses Cyrillic alphabets predominantly ;) ). Also, **please tell us [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)**. Apart from demonstrating effort, it will also show us the context of the question better. And, actually, do include examples written in Cyrillic script if you need them, but take care to describe their relevance and meaning.

Answer (score -1):

I can't give you the full code, but if it can get you started... I recommend:

1. "Splitting" your string into the groups of characters you want by matching it with

   ```
   /\b[a-zA-Z]+\b|[^a-zA-Z]/g
   ```

   This regex wil match words with `\b[a-zA-Z]+\b` with `\b` being a word boundary, or `[^a-zA-Z]` any other character non alphabetic. You will end up with a list of matches.
2. Going through your matches one by one, wrapping your results in the correct tags by incrementing the id and checking:

   - if the first character is a space, then `class="space"`
   - if the first character is a letter, then `class="word"`
   - else `class="sign"`

Careful, the first regex will count `...` as three separated characters, as well as `123` as three separated signs. You could adapt it with

```
/\b[a-zA-Z]+\b|\b\d+\b|\.\.\.|[^a-zA-Z]/g
```

and add as many special cases as you want, you get the idea.